# Can pickles (like beetroot) be frozen?

Tags: freezing, pickles

Living alone I can not resist buying pots of pickles.
But I do not dare to open them as I know I will not finish them before they go off, even when kept in the fridge. I have binned a few pots with at least half the pickles still in, gone nasty.

My question, can you freeze the pickles out of a freshly opened pot? My intention is to freeze them in 'one use' portions in plastic bags, so I can get them back to room temperature in the amount(s) I think I will use.
And if you can only do so with some of them, is there a list somewhere?
If I can freeze them, I expect them to be still nice to eat, not coming out as mush or dried out.

At this time I have beetroot, garlic and mini corn on the cob pickles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freeze pickles no problem. Please note that freezing will change the texture of your pickles. Freezing them faster will create smaller ice crystals which will generate less damage and thus less texture change.

For this reason I suggest pre-"freezing" a glass baking dish or heavy steel tray (like a baking steel) and refrigerate your pickles as cold as possible. Then lay your pickles out on it on parchment paper on the pre-chilled tray to let them freeze quickly. Once frozen, put them into individual bags with all the air removed (or wrap in freezer-safe cling wrap then put them into a bag). If you slice your pickles in half they will freeze even faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can freeze pickles, there are no safety considerations you need to be aware of. Freezing ruptures cells and can change the texture food, so your pickles may have a different consistency when they are thawed.

Comment: You can minimise the rupturing by freezing things very quickly. This why IVF is possible and how sushi is rid of worm eggs. Quick freezing also helps make nice ice cream.
-cool things down in the fridge first
-make the portions flat and not too large
-try not to wrap them in anything insulating.